# Help to numerically solve ODE

Tags: differential-equations

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912076/time-period-of-ode

Trying to numerically compute and compare the time period of an oscillation with the analytical solution suggested by Robert Israel. I get a wide discrapency, do not know what I miss here.

```
(*SineGordon_with _b _termXY.nb*)
Clear[x, y, Energy];
a = 1; b = -1; yi = Pi/6; xmax = 20.; ydi = 0;
SGEqBterm = {Y''[x] == a Sin[Y[x]] Cos[Y[x]] + b Cos[Y[x]], 
   Y'[0] == ydi, Y[0] == yi};
NDSolve[SGEqBterm, {Y}, {x, -2 xmax, 2 xmax}];
{y[u_]} = {Y[u]} /. First[%];
gp = Plot[{y[x]}, {x, 0, xmax}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic]
" next 4 lines prove constancy of energy as integration constant "
Plot[y'[x]^2 - a Sin[y[x]]^2 - 2 b Sin[y[x]], {x, 0, xmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Purple}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotLabel -> Energy]
Energy[u_] = y'[u]^2 - a Sin[y[u]]^2 - 2 b Sin[y[u]];
EE = Energy[y[3.45678]]
Plot[Energy[si], {si, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLabel -> Energy_f _y];
" next 3 lines are limits to evaluate definite integral which are \
roots of quadriatic equn  2 b s^2 + a s + E = 0 given in link "
x1 = -a/(4 b) - Sqrt[(a/(4 b))^2 - EE/(2 b)]; xmin = ArcSin[x1];
x2 = -a/(4 b) + Sqrt[(a/(4 b))^2 - EE/(2 b)]; xmax = ArcSin[x2];
{xmin, xmax}
" Quantity under radical sign QUR in the denominator of integral for \
numerical evaluation of elliptic integral . Plotted to verify it is \
>0 "
QUR[x_] = (a Sin[y[x]]^2 + 2 b Sin[y[x]] + EE);
g1 = Plot[QUR[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Purple}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> QtyUndrRadclSign]
T = NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[QUR[x]], {x, xmin, xmax}]
" computed T =34.1257 does not agree with plotted T = 10 "
```

Comment: It may be just me, but I'm finding the form of this question discourages me from investigating.  I have to go another site, read a few posts, and think about the problem to understand it.  A clear, self-contained statement of what is being sought and which two computations do not agree would be helpful.  Several lines of code do nothing, because they are terminated by semicolosn and the results discarded.  Other lines might be titles?  I wonder which things are important.  And I have to ask myself, do I want to get involved in something that looks like a hopeless tangle of ideas and code.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Sorry if it was so. I put in semicolon, to avoid repetitions so you can delete to see it on your run. Please give me a couple of hours, for straight code.

Comment: No problem.  While it might be just me, I thought it would be helpful to you to let you know that I didn't think many people would be encouraged to figure out this problem in its current form.  Already in the subject of diff. eqns., not many regular users contribute answers, so it helps to make the question as attractive as possible.  :)

Comment: Thanks Micheal, I appreciate this. In the link given, only Robert Israel's reply is necessary, and only on that I am working now. It is the same as non-linear pendulum ODE ( $ y^{''} + sin(y) = 0 $ ) type problem with one more term added, to reconcile between theoretical and numerical work.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Hope it is clearer now after edit, can still reply to any specific query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer:** 
There is a discrepancy (a) because there is an error in how you have implemented [Robert Israel's solution on the Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912076/time-period-of-ode) and (b) because his solution itself has an error.

**Long Answer:**
Buckle your seat belts, kids, this could be awhile.

## Part I: Numerical Solution for the Period

This bit of code gives Mathematica's numerical solution of the differential equation.

```
(* define some constants *)
a = 1;
b = -1;
yi = Pi/6;
xmax = 20.;
ydi = 0; (* 0 *)
(* define equation to solve *)
SGEqBterm = {Y''[x] == a Sin[Y[x]] Cos[Y[x]] + b Cos[Y[x]], Y'[0] == ydi, Y[0]== yi};
(* solve and plot solution *)
sol = First@NDSolve[SGEqBterm, Y, {x, -2 xmax, 2 xmax}];
y[u_] := Y[u] /. sol;
gp = Plot[{y[x]}, {x, 0, xmax}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

From a plot of the solution, it looks as if the period should be around 10.

[image: Mathematica solution]

This is confirmed by calculation of the period.

```
(* you can't look exactly at x=0 or else you run into some numerical issues *)
x1 = x /. FindMinimum[y[x], {x, 0.1}][[2]];
x2 = x /. FindMinimum[y[x], {x, 10}][[2]];
plotperiod = x2 - x1
9.95929
```

So far there isn't much difference between what I've done and what you've done (although I took some liberty in making the code a bit more readable).

## Part II: Analytic Solution for the Period

Next let's look at the analytic solution. For the sake of clarity and because I think there may be an error in the solution on the Math Stack Exchange (although the individual has a boatload of reputation is not likely prone to mistakes), I want to be thorough in my explanation.

The linked solution claims that the "energy" $E=(y')^2-asin^2(y)-2bsin(y)$ is conserved. Within the bounds of numerical precision, Mathematica's solution confirms this to be the case. So far, so good.

```
Energy[x_] := y'[x]^2 - a Sin[y[x]]^2 - 2 b Sin[y[x]];
EE = Energy[y[0]]
Plot[Energy[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLabel -> Energy_f _y]
```

[image: constant E]

Before using a numerical solution, we could have expected oscillatory behavior from the form of the differential equation (since it matches the general form of an oscillator in physics). Thus, there should be two "turn-around" points $y_1$ and $y_2$ for which *y* achieves a minimum and a maximum. Mathematically, this corresponds to the condition $y'(x)=0$ at these points. Define $s=sin(y)$, and this leads to the assertion that there are two solutions $s_1$ and $s_2$ for which $E=-as^2-2bs$. All this is in agreement with has been claimed in the Math Stack Exchange solution.

Locating these values for s then becomes a problem of finding roots of the equation $as^2+2bs+E=0$ (note that this is different from the incorrect roots you find in your code above).

```
{s1, s2} = s /. Solve[a s^2 + 2*b*s + EE == 0, s]
{0.5,1.5}
```

At first, this result confused me for a long time. `ArcSin[1.5]` is a complex number, but we know that the solution for y is strictly real in the domain of interest. After some careful thinking, I came to conclude following: since *y* oscillates to positive and negative values, there will be two values of *y* for which $Sin(y)=0.5$ in a given period. The two necessary values of *s* are $s_1=s_2=0.5$ and the solution $s=1.5$ is extraneous. These two values correspond to $y_1=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $y_2=\frac{-7\pi}{6}$. Encouragingly, these are in fact the minimum and maximum y values in the plot above.

With that in mind, let's calculate the period.

If the minimum and maximum *y* values occur at $y_1=y(x_1)$ and $y_2=y(x_2)$, then the period of the oscillation is

$$T = 2 \int_{x_1}^{x_2} dx $$

Now from the energy expression above, we have that $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{E+asin^2(y)+2bsin(y)}$. Thus the integral to obtain the period can be re-expressed as:

$$ T = 2 \int_{y_1}^{y_2} \frac{dy}{\sqrt{E+asin^2(y)+2bsin(y)}}$$

The addition of the sin terms (as opposed to subtraction) is where I differentiate my solution from that of the linked Math Stack Exchange solution.

## Part III: Comparison With Part I

Let's try to numerically evaluate this integral. Because the sum of the sine terms approaches `EE` near the bounds of integration, the integrand blows up there. I found that I needed a small offset to avoid obtaining a complex value for the integral. The size of this offset depends on how precise you want the solution to be (I didn't bother messing with the precision much).

```
(* evaluate the analytic integral *)
eps = 5*10^-8;
ymin = -7 Pi/6;
ymax = Pi/6;
result = Block[{y},NIntegrate[2/Sqrt[+a*Sin[y]^2 + 2*b*Sin[y] + EE], {y, ymin + eps, ymax - eps}]]
9.95872
```

This is very close to the value obtained by solving the equation numerically from the outset.

**Period solution numerically:** 9.95929

**Period solution analytically:** 9.95872

It should perhaps be stated that these period values are exclusive to the initial conditions defined above, but I expect that these two approaches will give similar solutions independent of the initial conditions (I have not explicitly checked).

I hope this discussion has helped you reconcile the differences you first observed between the two approaches used.

Comment: Nice answer. I'd give you an extra +1, if I could, for being patient enough to work through the code and figure out what the question is.  Your answer made it easier for me to add my contribution.

Answer (score 2):

To add another method to [Jerro39](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/16407/jerro39) excellent answer, here is way to find the period from within `NDSolve`.  Since we are in a sense integrating the energy, it turns out to be more accurate to use the `"Projection"` method, which is explained in the tutorial [`NDSolveProjection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveProjection.html).  When can detect a period (assuming the solutions are periodic), by using `WhenEvent` to detect the time the system returns to its initial position.

```
Clear[energy];
a = 1;
b = -1;
yi = Pi/6;
xmax = 20.;
ydi = 0;
SGEqBterm = {y''[x] == a Sin[y[x]] Cos[y[x]] + b Cos[y[x]], y'[0] == ydi, y[0] == yi};

energy[y_, yd_] := yd^2 - a Sin[y]^2 - 2 b Sin[y];

sol = First@
   NDSolve[{SGEqBterm, 
     WhenEvent[y[x] == yi, period = x; "RemoveEvent", 
      "DetectionMethod" -> "DerivativeSign"]}, 
    y, {x, -2 xmax, 2 xmax}, 
    Method -> {"Projection", "Invariants" -> {energy[y[x], y'[x]]}}];
period
(*
  9.95928
*)
```

If the system has a more complicated trajectory, the return to the initial condition might better be checked with something like this:

```
WhenEvent[y[x] == yi,
 If[Abs[y'[x] - ydi] < 10^-6, period = x; "RemoveEvent"],
 "DetectionMethod" -> "DerivativeSign"]
```

Note: I changed many of the symbols beginning with capitals to lowercase.  It's a good practice, to avoid clashing with built-in symbols.